# R: Is there an equivalent of Stata's 'compare' command in R - comparing variables?

Tags: r, compare, stata

In Stata there is a simple method to compare two variables in a dataset using the `compare` command (https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dcompare.pdf). I was wondering is there an equivalent in R. Rather than just saying are they equivalent it gives a detailed comparison of the variables, see link above.

In R, if you had a dataset (`df`) and two variables (`variable1`,`variable2`) you could create a variable,

`df$compare<- ifelse(df$variable1==df$variable2,0,1)`

and you could also calculate the difference between them

`df$diff<- df$variable1-df$variable2`

and explore these variables by whether the variables were equal/greater than/less than each other, but I wonder has someone created a simple wrapper function that displays the results similarly to Stata.

```
. webuse fullauto
(Automobile Models)

. compare rep77 rep78

                                        ---------- difference ----------
                            count       minimum      average     maximum
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rep77<rep78                    16            -3      -1.3125          -1
rep77=rep78                    43
rep77>rep78                     7             1            1           1
                       ----------
jointly defined                66            -3    -.2121212           1
rep77 missing only              3
jointly missing                 5
                       ----------
total                          74
```

Comment: Don't ask people to read other documents: you'll cut your readership that way. Show an example. I've taken the liberty of doing it for you. I'll bet in advance that the answer is "Yes, that's programmable, but no one has done precisely that".

Comment: As a general rule, questions asking tools, libraries or just functionalities are off-topic in SO. As you said, what the `compare` does in Stata is easily reproducible in R. So, go ahead and try it yourself. If then you meet some difficulty in doing it, ask a specific, programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

The `all.equal` functionality is probabably what gets closest to what you want in base R. Try to run `?all.equal` for more information.

This function compares many classes within a specified tolerance (in case of numerics).